# Excel vlookup with 3 criteria

Tags: excel

I'm trying to have a formula that basically does a vlookup with multiple criteria. Since the fields are date and time fields, I tried concatenating the cells that I need and got the dates converted to random numbers, so I was unable to do it.

Basically, I am finding a value in column D of a reference table such that col A = col A of reference table, col B = col B of ref table, and col C = col C of ref table. How do I go about this? Thanks

Comment: Is the value in D numeric? If so, use SUMIFS.

Comment: `=INDEX(column_to_lookup_value_from, MATCH(1,INDEX((criteria1 = range1)*(criteria2 = range2)*(criteria3 = range3),0,1),0))`

Comment: Dates are not converted to random numbers, but the days from Jan 1st 1900. So, for example, if you convert October 15th 2019 in numeric it will give you 43.753, which is the days from 1/1/1900 to 15/10/2019. So the concatenate technique should work. But, @Mako212 answer works super!! Thank you I didn't knew that I could use the MATCH function this way